# I want to show Action Bar with date string and next and previous button on it.

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-actionbar

[image: Action bar with date and buttons]

What steps should i perform in order to achieve it ?

I have already created action bar but i am stuck with further steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a "custom view":

```
actionbar.setCustomView(your_custom_view)
actionbar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

Tutorial:

http://javatechig.com/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android

Answer (score 1):

try like this,

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.your_custom_actionbar_view);
actionBar.setIcon(null);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
```

hopw it will help you